# Position a image button in a table cell

Tags: html, css

I want to position my image button to the bottom-right in a table cell but when I insert more/less text I don't want the button to change position. How do I do that?

I don't really know how to do it but I'll post my current html code.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            <%--<umbraco:Item field="nyhet-1-text" runat="server" />--%>
            <p><img src=""/></p>
            <p><strong>News</strong></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <a href="#"class="readMoreButton"><img src="../media/testImage.png" alt="test"/></a>
        </div> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

/Kristian

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float:right;` on the the .readMoreButton which will mean the button will always be stuck to the right had side of its parent container.  It will be pushed down the page when the content grows.

```css
.readMoreButton{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            <p><img src=""/></p>
            <p><strong>News</strong></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <a href="#"class="readMoreButton"><img src="../media/testImage.png" alt="test"/></a>
        </div> 
    </td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. float:right; But I don't want the button to grow. On the <p> the text length is max 4 rows. But I don't want the button to move up or down.

Comment: How do you mean grow? Does the code not provide the layout you have shown in your image?

Comment: Sorry for missunderstanding. Either I got 1 rows with text or 4 rows with text I want the button to always align to the bottom right of the td. Since I've been using CSS to allow maximum 4 rows of text on the paragraph.

Comment: When you have 4 rows does each row have a button? or is there still 1 button under all the 4 rows?